# How to actually get bone and animation data with assimp?

Tags: assimp

Hello Im trying to import animation and bones data from a FBX file.

I actually tried with several different models in different formats, but no matter what I Do it always says 
scene->mNumAnimations = 0;
scene->mNumBones = 0;

What could be happening?

Comment: Which model have you imported. Did you try our samples?

Comment: Actually the problem was a flag called pre-transform  bones.

Comment: Actually the flag is called `aiProcess_PreTransformVertices`, but thanks a lot, it resolved my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What assimp uses to animate the models is a bone chain based on the meshes. We have a bone hierarchy which stores the affected vertices by the bone animation. The bones itself are descriped by an offset-matrix, which is just the inverse of the global transform for the current mesh in respect to the root-node of your animation hierarchy. This comes from the X-Fileformat and I want to add a better way to descripe bone-animations.

The pretransform-bone-post-processor will perform the transformation after the import directly. So your bones will be gone.